# Synchronizing Thunderbird15.0.1-Contacts with cardDAV-Server without using SOGO-Connector

Tags: sync, thunderbird, contacts

I have my own server (running 12.04) on which I installed ownCloud and were able to successfully synchronize my  Calendar via CalDAV. But when trying to synchronize my contacts with CardDAV, nothing worked. Everywhere I searched, all I could find was using SOGO-Connector which didn't work at all.

By the way: One thing SOGO-Connector did, was asking me twice for my master password every time I started Thunderbird.

Is this an ownCloud-specific (v. 4.04) problem?

If anyone has a solution wihout ownCloud or without cardDAV in general, this is fine, but it shouldn't store my contact data anywhere else than on my server (that means no cloud storage solution).

It may help to know, that I have a working SparkleShare synchronisation.

EDIT: Now using Radicale instead of ownCloud but with the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my own problem:

1. Installing Evolution and adding the CardDAV-adressbook
2. Installing EDS Contact Integration into Thunderbird

That's it, wasn't that hard.

Only problem: You have to specify an email account at least once to setup evolution (can be removed later).

Comment: Evolution does not support CardDAV fully, either; you'll get read-only syncing.

Comment: @Raphael I've been using Evolution with CardDAV and bidirectional syncing for quite some time now. It's definitely not read only. The server component is hosted via owncloud. I've stopped using Thunderbird though.

Comment: Really? As far as I know, Evolution can only do WebDAV for contacts, i.e. read-only when it comes to CardDAV. Do you use SyncEvolution?

Comment: @Raphael It's listed as WebDAV. I've been working under the assumption that Contacts via WebDAV *is* CardDav, but that may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cardbook addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/cardbook/?src=hp-dl-upandcoming) completely replaces Thunderbird's built-in address book and provides support for CardDAV. It directly connects to your server using URL, username and password -- no data leakage (as far as I can tell without having checked the sources). This seems to work fine with my own Radicale server.

*Nota bene:* If you use HTTPS with a server that does not have a valid certificate (in particular a self-signed one) you need to add an exception for that server in Thunderbird's certificate configuration dialogue first. Otherwise, Cardbook will just report failed validation of the login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround in my special case:

The personal adressbook integrated in thunderbird is located in a file called abook.mab. Synchronizing this file with the help of a symlink and SparkleShare synchronizes my adressbook without using CardDAV.